# What is the license for Flyway embedded in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

I use Spring Boot version `2.1.9.RELEASE` with flyway in dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I rely on Spring auto configuration to run Flyway's migration script in side `resources/db/migration` on the application start.

My customer found Flyway's pricing page (https://flywaydb.org/download/) and concerned about what license of Flyway is in this case.

Can I assume the license to be the same as Spring Boot license (Apache V2)?

Comment: If you are using the community edition the its Apache license.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam thanks, but I don't know if my version is community or not. Do you know how can I check it?

Comment: Open the JAR file using 7Zip and check the file `META-INF\LICENSE.txt` for license information.

Comment: That works. Thank you very much ^^